# Groovy: Json to XML dynamic

Tags: json, xml, groovy

We have a json like following

```
{
  "test" : { 
    "a" : "A", 
    "b" : "B"
  }
}
```

The final XML outcome to be generated is if there is an element present in test json object that should be converted into XML and another XML tag to be added to demonstrate that the element present is true.
like following:

```
<test>
  <message>
    <a>A</a>
    <b>B</b>
  </message>
  <booleanMessage>
    <a>true</a>
    <b>true</b>
  </booleanMessage>
</test>
```

How can we use groovy transformation to do so?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no direct way, you would have to write your own parser for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) and [MarkupBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilder.html) to achieve this.

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText('''
    {
      "test" : { 
        "a" : "A", 
        "b" : "B"
       }
    }
''')

def sw = new StringWriter()
def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(sw)

json.each { prop ->
    xml."$prop.key" {
        message {
            prop.value.each { nestedProp ->            
                "$nestedProp.key"(nestedProp.value)
            }   
        }
        booleanMessage {
            prop.value.each  { p ->
                "$p.key"('true')
            }               
        }
    }
}
println sw.toString()
```