# JSON to XML - Groovy: Caught: nu.xom.IllegalNameException: NCNames cannot start with the character <N>

Tags: json, xml, groovy

Groovy version: **2.4.6**
JAVA **1.7**

Trying to convert the following JSON blob into XML. I have other JSON blob entries which are different in structure, objects within the JSON from different Jenkins jobs, type of jobs, no. of parameters etc. End goal is to convert JSON file (from MongoDB collection; mongoexport command) to XML and finally import it into EXCEL rows (which is available in Excel out of the box under Data tab).

Sample JSON blob entry (verified by [JSON Pretty Print](http://jsonprettyprint.com/)) is:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5120349es967yhsdfs907c4f"
  },
  "actions": [
    {
      "causes": [
        {
          "shortDescription": "Started by an SCM change"
        }
      ]
    },
    {

    },
    {
      "oneClickDeployPossible": false,
      "oneClickDeployReady": false,
      "oneClickDeployValid": false
    },
    {

    },
    {

    },
    {

    },
    {
      "cspec": "element * .../MyProject_latest_int/LATESTnelement * .../MyProject_integration/LATESTnelement /vobs/some_vob/gigi /main/myproject_integration/MyProject_Slot_0_maint_int/LATESTnelement * .../myproject_integration/LATESTnelement /vobs/some_vob /main/LATEST",
      "latestBlsOnConfiguredStream": null,
      "stream": null
    },
    {

    },
    {
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "CLEARCASE_VIEWTAG",
          "value": "jenkins_MyProject_latest"
        },
        {
          "name": "BUILD_DEBUG",
          "value": false
        },
        {
          "name": "CLEAN_BUILD",
          "value": true
        },
        {
          "name": "BASEVERSION",
          "value": "7.4.1"
        },
        {
          "name": "ARTIFACTID",
          "value": "lowercaseprojectname"
        },
        {
          "name": "SYSTEM",
          "value": "myprojectSystem"
        },
        {
          "name": "LOT",
          "value": "02"
        },
        {
          "name": "PIPENUMBER",
          "value": "7.4.1.303"
        }
      ]
    },
    {

    },
    {

    },
    {
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "DESCRIPTION_SETTER_DESCRIPTION",
          "value": "lowercaseprojectname_V7.4.1.303"
        }
      ]
    },
    {

    },
    {

    },
    {

    },
    {

    }
  ],
  "artifacts": [

  ],
  "building": false,
  "builtOn": "servername",
  "changeSet": {
    "items": [
      {
        "affectedPaths": [
          "vobs/some_vob/myproject/apps/app1/Java/test/src/com/giga/highlevelproject/myproject/schedule/validation/SomeActivityTest.java"
        ],
        "author": {
          "absoluteUrl": "http://11.22.33.44:8080/user/hitj1620",
          "fullName": "name1, name2 A"
        },
        "commitId": null,
        "date": {
          "$numberLong": "1489439532000"
        },
        "dateStr": "13/03/2017 21:12:12",
        "elements": [
          {
            "action": "create version",
            "editType": "edit",
            "file": "/vobs/some_vob/myproject/apps/app1/Java/test/src/com/giga/highlevelproject/myproject/schedule/validation/SomeActivityTest.java",
            "operation": "checkin",
            "version": "/main/MyProject_latest_int/2"
          }
        ],
        "msg": "",
        "timestamp": -1,
        "user": "user111"
      }
    ],
    "kind": null
  },
  "culprits": [
    {
      "absoluteUrl": "http://11.22.33.44:8080/user/nuka1620",
      "fullName": "nuka, Chuck"
    }
  ],
  "description": "lowercaseprojectname_V7.4.1.303",
  "displayName": "#303",
  "duration": 525758,
  "estimatedDuration": 306374,
  "executor": null,
  "fullDisplayName": "MyProject u00bb MyProject-build #303",
  "highlevelproject_metrics_source_url": "http://11.22.33.44:8080/job/MyProject/job/MyProject-build/303//api/json",
  "id": "303",
  "keepLog": false,
  "number": 303,
  "projectName": "MyProject-build",
  "queueId": 8201,
  "result": "SUCCESS",
  "timeToRepair": null,
  "timestamp": {
    "$numberLong": "1489439650307"
  },
  "url": "http://11.22.33.44:8080/job/MyProject/job/MyProject-build/303/"
}
```

Tried some posts for JSON >>> XML conversion solutions but they are either custom solution or they didn't work to generate an output which can successfully be imported into an EXCEL file (via Excel's data import).

I used the following Groovy code:

```
import net.sf.json.JSON
import net.sf.json.JSONSerializer
import net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer

def str = "{ \"_id\": { \"$oid\": \"5120349es967yhsdfs907c4f\"}, \"actions\": [ { \"causes\": [ { \"shortDescription\": \"Started by an SCM change\"} ]}, {}, { \"oneClickDeployPossible\": false, \"oneClickDeployReady\": false, \"oneClickDeployValid\": false}, {}, {}, {}, { \"cspec\": \"element * .../MyProject_latest_int/LATESTnelement * .../MyProject_integration/LATESTnelement /vobs/some_vob/gigi /main/myproject_integration/MyProject_Slot_0_maint_int/LATESTnelement * .../myproject_integration/LATESTnelement /vobs/some_vob /main/LATEST\", \"latestBlsOnConfiguredStream\": null, \"stream\": null}, {}, { \"parameters\": [ { \"name\": \"CLEARCASE_VIEWTAG\", \"value\": \"jenkins_MyProject_latest\"}, { \"name\": \"BUILD_DEBUG\", \"value\": false}, { \"name\": \"CLEAN_BUILD\", \"value\": true}, { \"name\": \"BASEVERSION\", \"value\": \"7.4.1\"}, { \"name\": \"ARTIFACTID\", \"value\": \"lowercaseprojectname\"}, { \"name\": \"SYSTEM\", \"value\": \"myprojectSystem\"}, { \"name\": \"LOT\", \"value\": \"02\"}, { \"name\": \"PIPENUMBER\", \"value\": \"7.4.1.303\"} ]}, {}, {}, { \"parameters\": [ { \"name\": \"DESCRIPTION_SETTER_DESCRIPTION\", \"value\": \"lowercaseprojectname_V7.4.1.303\"} ]}, {}, {}, {}, {} ], \"artifacts\": [ ], \"building\": false, \"builtOn\": \"servername\", \"changeSet\": { \"items\": [ { \"affectedPaths\": [ \"vobs/some_vob/myproject/apps/app1/Java/test/src/com/giga/highlevelproject/myproject/schedule/validation/SomeActivityTest.java\" ], \"author\": { \"absoluteUrl\": \"http://11.22.33.44:8080/user/hitj1620\", \"fullName\": \"name1, name2 A\"}, \"commitId\": null, \"date\": { \"$numberLong\": \"1489439532000\"}, \"dateStr\": \"13/03/2017 21:12:12\", \"elements\": [ { \"action\": \"create version\", \"editType\": \"edit\", \"file\": \"/vobs/some_vob/myproject/apps/app1/Java/test/src/com/giga/highlevelproject/myproject/schedule/validation/SomeActivityTest.java\", \"operation\": \"checkin\", \"version\": \"/main/MyProject_latest_int/2\"} ], \"msg\": \"\", \"timestamp\": -1, \"user\": \"user111\"} ], \"kind\": null}, \"culprits\": [ { \"absoluteUrl\": \"http://11.22.33.44:8080/user/nuka1620\", \"fullName\": \"nuka, Chuck\"} ], \"description\": \"lowercaseprojectname_V7.4.1.303\", \"displayName\": \"#303\", \"duration\": 525758, \"estimatedDuration\": 306374, \"executor\": null, \"fullDisplayName\": \"MyProject u00bb MyProject-build #303\", \"highlevelproject_metrics_source_url\": \"http://11.22.33.44:8080/job/MyProject/job/MyProject-build/303//api/json\", \"id\": \"303\", \"keepLog\": false, \"number\": 303, \"projectName\": \"MyProject-build\", \"queueId\": 8201, \"result\": \"SUCCESS\", \"timeToRepair\": null, \"timestamp\": { \"$numberLong\": \"1489439650307\"}, \"url\": \"http://11.22.33.44:8080/job/MyProject/job/MyProject-build/303/\"}" 
JSON json = JSONSerializer.toJSON( str )
XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer()
xmlSerializer.setTypeHintsCompatibility( false )
String xml = xmlSerializer.write( json )
System.out.println(xml)
```

Which is giving me the following error message, why am I getting this error when JSON lint/validation shows it's a valid JSON:

```
Caught: nu.xom.IllegalNameException: NCNames cannot start with the character 24
nu.xom.IllegalNameException: NCNames cannot start with the character 24
       at nu.xom.Verifier.throwIllegalNameException(Unknown Source)
       at nu.xom.Verifier.checkNCName(Unknown Source)
       at nu.xom.Element._setLocalName(Unknown Source)
       at nu.xom.Element.<init>(Unknown Source)
       at nu.xom.Element.<init>(Unknown Source)
       at net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer.newElement(XMLSerializer.java:869)
       at net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer.processJSONObject(XMLSerializer.java:989)
       at net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer.processJSONValue(XMLSerializer.java:1040)
       at net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer.processJSONObject(XMLSerializer.java:990)
       at net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer.write(XMLSerializer.java:605)
       at net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer.write(XMLSerializer.java:570)
       at net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer$write$0.call(Unknown Source)
       at ConvertJson2xml.run(ConvertJson2xml.groovy:110)
       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Why not use groovy's XML writing and json parsing classes that come with the language https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37592450/groovy-json-to-xml-dynamic? Why not write the Excel document directly instead of via some XML format?  With http://jameskleeh.com/groovy-excel-builder/ for example?

Comment: @tim_yates When you say Groovy's XML writing, did you mean write custom code? If yes, it wont work. In one mongodb collection, I have 100s of Jenkins jobs (changed over time for its parameters, configs etc) and which contains unstructured JSON data. The end goal is to import key=value pair into Excel. JSON data can't go to Excel out of the box thus, I thought I should convert JSON to XML first. Writing Excel document directly makes sense, but would be more work which will require maintained code (as I mentioned, multiple jobs in one collection with different structure due to various plugins)

Comment: @tim_yates I would like to see your inputs if you can point which class I can use. The solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937254/convert-json-to-xml-using-groovy is not generic (i.e. it's custom to that post's data fields). Trying `JSON2CSV, JSONV` (GitHub) or `JQ` would take some time to implement here (policies/procedures).

Comment: XML names may not begin with `$`.  If you want to convert to XML, you'll have to ensure that the converted names [begin with an allowed character](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar).

Comment: @kjhughes exactly. Just figured it out. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @tim_yates The code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37592450/groovy-json-to-xml-dynamic is not generic. For my JSON blob (after removing the `$` sign), I still got errors. `Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: key for class: java.lang.Boolean` and when I commented out the Boolean part, it errored for string part `Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: key for class: java.lang.String`

Answer (score 0):

OK. It was a valid JSON but that doesn't mean it'd be a valid XML as well.

Seems like `$` sign is not allowed in object names in XML format while conversion from JSON to XML.

**Removing ** `$` in the JSON blob, **Resolved!!** the following issue:

To remove it (`sed`  or `tr -d '$'` can do that).

```
def str = "{ \"_id\": { \"oid\": \"5120349es967yhsdfs907c4f\"}, \"actions\": [ { \"causes\": [ { \"shortDescription\": \"Started by an SCM change\"} ]}, {}, { \"oneClickDeployPossible\": false, \"oneClickDeployReady\": false, \"oneClickDeployValid\": false}, {}, {}, {}, { \"cspec\": \"element * .../MyProject_latest_int/LATESTnelement * .../MyProject_integration/LATESTnelement /vobs/some_vob/gigi /main/myproject_integration/MyProject_Slot_0_maint_int/LATESTnelement * .../myproject_integration/LATESTnelement /vobs/some_vob /main/LATEST\", \"latestBlsOnConfiguredStream\": null, \"stream\": null}, {}, { \"parameters\": [ { \"name\": \"CLEARCASE_VIEWTAG\", \"value\": \"jenkins_MyProject_latest\"}, { \"name\": \"BUILD_DEBUG\", \"value\": false}, { \"name\": \"CLEAN_BUILD\", \"value\": true}, { \"name\": \"BASEVERSION\", \"value\": \"7.4.1\"}, { \"name\": \"ARTIFACTID\", \"value\": \"lowercaseprojectname\"}, { \"name\": \"SYSTEM\", \"value\": \"myprojectSystem\"}, { \"name\": \"LOT\", \"value\": \"02\"}, { \"name\": \"PIPENUMBER\", \"value\": \"7.4.1.303\"} ]}, {}, {}, { \"parameters\": [ { \"name\": \"DESCRIPTION_SETTER_DESCRIPTION\", \"value\": \"lowercaseprojectname_V7.4.1.303\"} ]}, {}, {}, {}, {} ], \"artifacts\": [ ], \"building\": false, \"builtOn\": \"servername\", \"changeSet\": { \"items\": [ { \"affectedPaths\": [ \"vobs/some_vob/myproject/apps/app1/Java/test/src/com/giga/highlevelproject/myproject/schedule/validation/SomeActivityTest.java\" ], \"author\": { \"absoluteUrl\": \"http://11.22.33.44:8080/user/hitj1620\", \"fullName\": \"name1, name2 A\"}, \"commitId\": null, \"date\": { \"numberLong\": \"1489439532000\"}, \"dateStr\": \"13/03/2017 21:12:12\", \"elements\": [ { \"action\": \"create version\", \"editType\": \"edit\", \"file\": \"/vobs/some_vob/myproject/apps/app1/Java/test/src/com/giga/highlevelproject/myproject/schedule/validation/SomeActivityTest.java\", \"operation\": \"checkin\", \"version\": \"/main/MyProject_latest_int/2\"} ], \"msg\": \"\", \"timestamp\": -1, \"user\": \"user111\"} ], \"kind\": null}, \"culprits\": [ { \"absoluteUrl\": \"http://11.22.33.44:8080/user/nuka1620\", \"fullName\": \"nuka, Chuck\"} ], \"description\": \"lowercaseprojectname_V7.4.1.303\", \"displayName\": \"#303\", \"duration\": 525758, \"estimatedDuration\": 306374, \"executor\": null, \"fullDisplayName\": \"MyProject u00bb MyProject-build #303\", \"highlevelproject_metrics_source_url\": \"http://11.22.33.44:8080/job/MyProject/job/MyProject-build/303//api/json\", \"id\": \"303\", \"keepLog\": false, \"number\": 303, \"projectName\": \"MyProject-build\", \"queueId\": 8201, \"result\": \"SUCCESS\", \"timeToRepair\": null, \"timestamp\": { \"numberLong\": \"1489439650307\"}, \"url\": \"http://11.22.33.44:8080/job/MyProject/job/MyProject-build/303/\"}"
```

**Caught: nu.xom.IllegalNameException: NCNames cannot start with the character** .