# JIRA ScriptRunner REST Endpoint- How to return response as XML content type?

Tags: xml, rest, groovy, jira, jira-rest-api

I have tried the following example:

```
import...

@BaseScript CustomEndpointDelegate delegate 

doSomething( 
    httpMethod: "GET", groups: ["jira-administrators"] 
) { MultivaluedMap queryParams, String body -> 
    return Response.ok("my response").build() 
}
```

from [here](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/rest-endpoints.html)

Always the content type of the response is JSON.
How can i chang it to XML please?

Answer (score 0):

The output of Jira's REST API is always JSON, so you'll have to do the conversion to XML within in your groovy code.

Try reading [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937254/convert-json-to-xml-using-groovy) and [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37592450/groovy-json-to-xml-dynamic) for some examples.